# Oci_bind_by_name is not working when using it with like clause

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm trying to use oci_bind_by_name to bind php variables into sql statment, but it is not working, this is my code

```
     $keyword="'%test%'";
     $stmt=oci_parse($connection,"SELECT *  
     FROM tableName where id=:id and (dataDetails like :key1 or  textData like :key1 or  name like :key1) and lang = :lang ");
           oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $id);
           oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':key1', $keyword);
           oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':lang', $lang);
           oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

after fetching  $stmt it give me noth. what's wrong? any help?

Comment: Maybe you're not allowed to use the same placeholder multiple times. Try using `:key1`, `:key2`, `:key3`.

Comment: Also, does `$keyword` have wildcard characters? If not, you probably need to do `$keyword = '%'.$keyword.'%'`.

Comment: I tried to use :key1,:key2,and :key3 the same thing, and the variable $keyword have wildcard as $keyword="'%test%'"; correct me if I am wrong

Comment: When you added `:key1`, `:key1` etc, do you also increase the number of calls to `oci_bind_by_name` to take into account these additional bind variables?

Comment: no I dont.. let me try it

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your value without single quotes and then concatenate your bound value for the like comparison:

```
 $keyword="test";
 $stmt=oci_parse($connection,"SELECT *  
 FROM tableName where id=:id and (dataDetails like '%' || :key1 || '%' or  textData like '%' || :key1 || '%' or  name like '%' || :key1 || '%') and lang = :lang ");
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $id);
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':key1', $keyword);
       oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':lang', $lang);
       oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
```